# How can I fallback to a go implementation when cgo is not available during build?

Tags: go, fallback, cgo

My project could benefit from some cgo code, but I have a fallback implementation in go to use when cgo is not available during build.

However, when I build without cgo, I get the error `C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG`.

The C code is only used in a file marked with `// +build cgo` and there is an alternative available with `// +build !cgo`.

How do I set things up so I can build with cgo where available, but also keep supporting the fallback behaviour?

FWIW, the code is at https://github.com/raboof/connbeat/tree/tcp_diag and the error can be triggered with a 'make crosscompile'.

Comment: What version of go are you using? (this works in go1.7, I just don't remember when it was fixed)

Comment: I can confirm it works with 1.7beta2 on travis but not on go 1.6.1 on my local machine